# Return true doesn't work but return false does

Tags: python

How come

```
def allEven(n):
    for c in n:
            if c % 2 != 0:
                    return False
    return True
```

works but

```
def allEven(n):
    for c in n:
            if c % 2 == 0:
                    return True
    return False
```

doesn't?
With the second one, when I type allEven([8, 0, -1, 4, -6, 10]), it says it's True.

Comment: The first one is a fluke. Try `allOdd` for the first one, modifying the condition.

Comment: The `return` statement in the *for* terminates the *for* prematurely. Not all the items are checked. Use the builtin `all` instead.

Comment: It doesn't work because it doesn't do what you expect it to do. It returns `True` when it meets a divisible by 2 element in the list. Obviously it will return `True` on `[8,0,-1,4,-6,10]` because `8` is divisible by 2. In other words second implementation is `anyEven`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone!

Answer (score 5):

In your second method, you `return True` once you find an even `c` in `n` which is not what your method supposed to do: return true IFF **all** `c`s are even.

Answer (score 1):

`Return` Statement terminate loop and end program. If `c % 2 == 0` is True, it Return `True` and terminate program not check all values.

Try This

```
def allEven(n):
    for c in n:
        if c % 2 == 0:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
```